# What does "spray" mean in football (soccer) context?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "spray" mean in football (soccer) context?

61 | Good counter from the Millers.

> Crooks **sprays** the ball out to Ladapo who finds Giles in the area. His cross takes a deflection off a Reading boot and is eventually cleared.

Answer (score 2):

It's a fairly uncommon figurative usage. Sports commentators often say "odd" things, some of which make it into more general acceptance (but *most don't* - so far, including this one).

The reference is to ***forcefully expelling*** (as, say, ***sneezing*** forcefully expels saliva/mucus), so the primary implication is it was a ***sudden, powerful*** kick to make the pass. But you probably won't find any particularly relevant examples of this usage in dictionaries, and it's unlikely you'd ever want to use it yourself.

Perhaps a more relevant allusion than ***sneezing*** is [***spraying machine gun fire***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sprayed%20machine%20gun%20fire%22). Particularly noting that it would be extremely common to have written *Crooks **fires** the ball out to Ladapo...*